# SSIS Package For Loading Data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SQL Server database with defined (1) tables, (2) corresponding views, and (3) stored procedures.

To my knowledge there is one and only one SSIS package, which takes care of the process of loading the data in the mentioned database.

At the end there is a web interface for the end user simply makes `SELECT` statements on top of one view in the database and displays the data.

Problem I am facing with is - some values (specific logs) are outdated.
It means - the load job (SSIS package) executes successfully,  however does not displays the newest data.

I am assuming that the problem is because either the log files are not placed where they should be placed, or the source for the logs has changed.

Therefore, I opened the productive version of the SSIS package. But then I go the error messages:

> The script is corrupted.
>   There were errors during task validation.

There should be no errors, because the package runs every day successfully.

I tried to find something like 'Rebuild the Project' option, but could not find anything.

How can I test it in order to find the cause for outdated rows?

-> Where in the package can I see for example where a particular table is being filled?

Answer (score -2):

You should open the ssis package with the proper version of BIDS or visual studio. i.e. the SSIS packages differ from SQL 2008 or SQL 2012. which version of SQL is the package made with and with which tool are you opening the package

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: No it doesn't, I am asking for clarification before I can provide an answer.